# Android getParent() is null but parentActivityName is set

Tags: android, activity-stack

I have a child activity that updates the database, which is shown in a table below in the parent activity. When the parent activity (Update) is done, a commit is send to the database and the data will be updated. Afterwards I would like to close Update and go back to my parent activity Display. This works, but the data is not refreshed. I read online that there is a simple method to recreate an activity..

> public void recreate ()
>
> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new
>   instance. This results in essentially the same flow as when the
>   Activity is created due to a configuration change -- the current
>   instance will go through its life cycle to onDestroy() and a new
>   instance then created after it.

So I call the UpdateActivity from the DisplayActivity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(app, UpdateActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And within the Update there is a button that does:

```
getParent().recreate();
finish();
```

However getParent() returns null and I get an error. Why is that?

I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml (Ofc. more but did not list everything)

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplaySearchResultActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:parentActivityName=".SearchActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UpdateActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".DisplaySearchResultActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about starting your `UpdateActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` ? 
You can read about it here : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result. With that in your `DisplayActivity` you can implement `onActivityResult()` function, which will `recreate()` itself. This should work fine. You won't have to call `getParent()`

`getParent()` documentation says `Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.` Your activity is not an embedded child. It's not part of `ActivityGroups` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.